# How to disable IPv6 short hostname resolution

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved, host-name-resolution

For a long time I've been able to SSH to other hosts on my network just with the short name, e.g. `ssh otherpc` and it recognises it's a short name, adds the DNS search suffix, does a lookup for `otherpc.mydomain.example` and that matches my SSH config for `*.mydomain.example` so the right private key is picked up.

However now I am finding that `ssh otherpc` is failing telling me the key is invalid.  If I `ping otherpc` then I get an IPv6 response from `otherpc` (note short name), whereas `ping -4 otherpc` returns responses from `otherpc.mydomain.example` (note full name).

Somehow when IPv4 is in use the DNS suffix works, but when IPv6 is in use it is able to look up the host by short name only, which means all my SSH rules that apply to the whole domain get ignored.

I run BIND as DNS daemon and it has forward and reverse entries for the whole domain (but nothing for short names only) so I'm not sure what or how the short names are being resolved.  I am running systemd-resolved so I am suspecting it's something that systemd is doing, but I'm not having any luck finding out what.

I thought it could've been LLMNR however disabling this in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` didn't help, and indeed if I terminate systemd-resolved then the problem still happens even though it's no longer running (probably because I had to turn off the DNS stub listener as it was conflicting with the DNS server on the machine).  So it looks like this short name resolution is happening somewhere else outside of systemd-resolved?

Does anyone know how this short hostname resolution works, and more importantly, how to turn it off and go back to the old method that adds a DNS suffix so SSH works again?

Comment: Short name resolution is based on `/etc/resolv.conf` entry `search`. I use ir regularly to add domains, for which I want shot names to work. If you put `search mydomain`in `/etc/resolv.conf`, name resolution will add mydomain to a host when you will enter only a short name. You can add more domain names after search keyword if you want. Name resolution tries them all. However, I am not sure how this works with some linuxes where they setup forwarding DNS and `/etc/resolv.conf` is generated and should not be changed manually. Read this: https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf

Comment: @nobody: There is already a `search` entry with the domain in `resolv.conf`, but it is not being used.  Something else is resolving the short name on its own, which means it never tries the search suffixes, as those are only used when nothing matches the short hostname.  (Which is traditionally the case unless you have it listed in `/etc/hosts`.)  My issue is that the `search` statement in my `resolv.conf` is not being used when I want it to be used.

Comment: `ssh_config` can also arbitrarily map short names to longer names. About IPv4/IPv6 I would also double check `/etc/gai.conf`.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: I want to avoid changing the SSH config as although it can match arbitrary names, I don't want to have to list out dozens of hostnames that are already in DNS, maintain it when new machines come online, and replicated it amongst all the machines as well - a task that DNS was specifically designed to avoid!  I think getting DNS to work as designed is by far the better option.  I didn't know about `gai.conf` but I can't see anything in there to do with DNS.  Which parts of it are you suggesting to change?

Comment: `gai.conf` is not related to DNS but how the OS presents IP addresses back to applications, if it favors IPv6 or IPv4 first.

Comment: Ah yes, I think my issue arises before it gets to the IP address stage, when it's still deciding which hostname to query in DNS, although admittedly I'm not sure why I'm seeing different behaviour in IPv4 vs IPv6.